# How to fetch and display data from some other ecommerce sites to my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

I want to get products related data from other ecommerce sites to my website.
 its just process like giving specific product url from other ecommerce site to display
 that product info in my website.

I am looking for this solution in Ruby On Rails.

Is there any solution with ror ? Please share your ideas If you knew about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific, give more details of your use case, and some idea of the specific data, and what approaches you have investigated (and ideally tried, at least in some debug environment). There are lots of ways to connect sites, from screen-scraping to using published APIs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of achieving what you need:

1) Those sites might actually have an API which you can use to get your job done.

2) Scraping those sites. Now, some websites for obvious reasons prohibit such thing so do read their terms. At any rate there are a couple of things you can use for web scraping like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials). A good screencast to get you started can be found on [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri)

There are a plethora of options for web scraping, depending what you actually need but get started with Nokogiri and you can then find out more eg [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/), a library used for automating interactions with a website. Another screenshot that can be found on [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize)